# Codename One Floating Action Button: change icon size without change fab size

Tags: codenameone

**This question is referred to Codename One only.**

I have these three FABs inside a `Form`:

[image]

I want them of the same size, but with the icons inside them bigger, like so:

[image]

I'm using CSS to style these FABs:

```
FABGreen {
    color: white;
    background-color: green;
}

FABRed {
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
}

FABGray {
    color: white;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

If I add `font-size: 5mm` nothing changes. If I use `FloatingActionButton.setIconDefaultSize(5);` it changes the FABs size, but I want them of the same size with bigger icons inside.

This is an example of the code I'm using inside the `Form`:

```
// FAB to discard changes
        FloatingActionButton fabDiscardChanges = FloatingActionButton.createFAB(FontImage.MATERIAL_REFRESH, "FABGray");
        fabDiscardChanges.addActionListener(e -> {

        });
        Container fabDiscardChangesCnt = fabDiscardChanges.bindFabToContainer(new Container(), Component.RIGHT, Component.TOP);
        fabs.add(fabDiscardChangesCnt);
```

Comment: FYI according to the material design document you should never have more than one FAB per form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the result of:

```
FloatingActionButton.setIconDefaultSize(10);
FloatingActionButton fab = FloatingActionButton.createFAB(FontImage.MATERIAL_ADD);
fab.bindFabToContainer(hi);
```

[image]

I'm guessing that the part that bothers you is the padding around the icon. You just need to reduce the padding. The UI uses double padding both for the FAB and the icon within it.

Comment: Thank you, but after a lot of attemps with CSS and Java I wasn't able to get what I asked. It seems that padding and margin (and even the border) are ignored if applied by CSS to the FABs' UIID or to the FloatingActionText UIID. I don't know how to access the padding around the icon.

Comment: I see the problem, it's caused by a behavior in preferred size that goes further than the padding. I added a static method that lets you disable it here https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/f2d75b38aa2c2d5f9186ec86749ba83d8600edb4 just use `FloatingActionButton.setAutoSizing(false)`

Comment: Ok, but I didn't find any way to set the internal padding. For example, `FloatingActionButton.setAutoSizing(false);
FloatingActionButton.setIconDefaultSize(7);
FloatingActionButton.setDefaultGap(Display.getInstance().convertToPixels(2));` makes the internal icon of the desidered size, but doesn't add 2mm of padding. I also tried with CSS on each FAB, without success.

Comment: The padding in the `FloatingActionButton` UIID should be used for the FAB. Notice it will be double once for the FAB itself and again in the icon

Comment: SOLVED, thank you again. What you implemented works perfectly in a simple test case, but it didn't work in my project. Finally I solved adding `header.forceRevalidate();` (the `header` is a Container for the FABs).

Comment: Did you invoke `FloatingActionButton.setAutoSizing(false)` before creating any FAB's? You can invoke it in the `init(Object)` method

Comment: Yes, I invoked it before creating any FAB. Probably the problem was caused by a hierarchy of nested Containers. My FABs are not binded to the contentPane but to a nested Container, that is created and added to another Container before creating the FABs.